# Looping through dictionary in Swift 3 errror

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I have a dictionary that I declare like so:

```
var dictBarData = [String: Any]()
```

I then declare and populate a second dictionary like so, and then add the second dictionary to the first:

```
var dictThisBar = [String:Any]()
        dictThisBar["category"] = category
        dictThisBar["barValue"] = value
        dictThisBar["barView"] = vThisBar

        dictBarData[String(barIndex)] = dictThisBar
```

When I go to retrieve them I do this:

```
for (key, value) in dictBarData {
            let dictThisBar = dictBarData[key]
            for(key, value) in dictThisBar {
            }
        }
```

But I am getting an error on the second for loop, type Any does not conform to protocol sequence. Type Any does not conform to sequence protocol

Answer (score 0):

According to the declaration all values in `dictBarData` are `Any`.

You have to cast the value down to

```
let dictThisBar = dictBarData[key] as! [String:Any]
```

However it's highly recommended to use optional bindings

```
if let dictThisBar = dictBarData[key] as? [String:Any] { ...
```